# Citation not found?

Tags: bibtex

I have just started with Latex, but have read several guides.

I get the following error :

> Citation `Chaparro2011DataDriven' on page 2 undefined
>
> Empty `thebibliography' environment
>
> There were undefined citations.

My code is (simplified):

```
\cite{Chaparro2011DataDriven}
```

and in the main file:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\label{Bibliography}

\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}} % Change the page header to say "Bibliography"

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % Use the "unsrtnat" BibTeX style for formatting the Bibliography

\bibliography{bibliography} % The references (bibliography) information are stored in the file named "Bibliography.bib"
```

The problem is when I write `\cite` and the auto suggestion comes up and I choose one, it chooses wrong keywords. For example if the reference in the BIB file is "Reference3", when I choose that article it inputs a name like `\cite{reference3_articleblabla}`

Comment: you forgot to run `bibtex <file>`

Comment: Actually found out what the problem is, I use sublime. And when I insert the Cite it inserts a different name than whats in the bibliography.. For example if the name is XX in the bibliography when I cite it inserts XX?__aa

Why?

Comment: So it is a Sublime problem and not a LaTeX problem?

Comment: I misunderstood how Latexing for Sublime worked. I exported a BIB from Mendely, and used that one... Thats wrong, as Latexing creates its own library.